# jpanel cannot make gridlayout with 7 rows and 2 cols

Tags: java, jpanel, grid-layout, border-layout

i want to ask if anything goes wrong with my code. i've set my frame with `borderlayout` . and on the center part, i want to use `gridlayout` with 7rows and 2 cols inside them.

```
        paneltengah= new JPanel();
        paneltengah.setLayout(new GridLayout(7,2));


        labelname = new JLabel(lbl_name,SwingConstants.LEFT);       
        labelusername = new JLabel(lbl_username,SwingConstants.LEFT);                                                                           
        labelpassword = new JLabel(lbl_password,SwingConstants.LEFT);               
        labelgender = new JLabel(lbl_gender,SwingConstants.LEFT);               
        labelemail = new JLabel(lbl_email,SwingConstants.LEFT);         
        labelhobby = new JLabel(lbl_hobby,SwingConstants.LEFT);             
        labelrole = new JLabel(lbl_role,SwingConstants.LEFT);

        textname = new JTextField(20);
        textusername = new JTextField(20);
        textpassword = new JPasswordField(20);
        textemail = new JTextField(20);
        comboboxhobby = new JComboBox();
        comboboxrole = new JComboBox();
        radiobuttonmale = new JRadioButton("Male");
        radiobuttonfemale = new JRadioButton("Female");
        ButtonGroup btngroup = new ButtonGroup();
        btngroup.add(radiobuttonmale);
        btngroup.add(radiobuttonfemale);



        paneltengah.add(labelname);
        paneltengah.add(labelusername);
        paneltengah.add(labelpassword);
        paneltengah.add(labelgender);
        paneltengah.add(labelemail);
        paneltengah.add(labelrole);
        paneltengah.add(labelhobby);

////        paneltengah.add(textname); when i open this, the layout become awkward      
////        paneltengah.add(textusername);
////        paneltengah.add(textpassword);
////        paneltengah.add(radiobuttonmale);
////        paneltengah.add(radiobuttonfemale);
////        paneltengah.add(comboboxhobby);
////        paneltengah.add(comboboxrole);


        pane.add(paneltengah, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

the following pictures is shown without opening the comment

[image]

the following picture is shown with uncomment

[image]

what is wrong with my code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, a `GridLayout` sizes all components evenly in its associated `Container`, which explains why your labels and fields are all the same size. For example, if you had a `JTextArea` 200 columns × 20 lines in your `JPanel`, then even the tiniest label would occupy that huge a space as well!

Next, according to the `GridLayout` Javadoc, when a `GridLayout` instance is constructed with two non-zero arguments, the number of rows gets fixed and the number of columns is adjusted according to the number of components put into the parent `Container`.

What I suggest is using a `BorderLayout` to set up your main form layout. Put your title at `NORTH` and keep the `CENTER` for your labels and fields (your current `JPanel`).

For your labels and fields, the simplest solution might be using a `GridLayout(0, 2)` (fixed number of columns). But all your components will still be equally sized.

If you need more control over the size of your components (e.g., fields wider than labels), then I suggest using another layout manager such as `GridBagLayout`. I know it's more complex to manage but using a `GridBagLayout` formatting preview utility should help. Such a program may be named something like `GridBagLab` (I know David Geary's book *Graphic Java* volume 2 — Swing features one on its companion CD).

There is also a `GridBagLayout` tutorial at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ts5fsHXIuvI.